100% CPU on 4 of 8 cores on Oracle Linux
I have a desktop computer (Intel i4770) running Oracle Linux 7.9 with kernel 4.1.12-61.  I usually keep it off and only turn it on on the rare occasions when I need to test something.  A month or so ago, I turned it on and noticed that the fans were on max speed - I checked top and found that setroubleshoot was at 100% so I killed the process.  The process kept coming back and I kept killing it but ultimately, it didn't matter much because my testing was done and I turned the computer off again.  (Yes, I always shut it down the right way.)
Now trying to get to the root of the problem, setroubleshoot is no longer showing 100% in top.  In fact, nothing is even close to 100%.  Running htop, I can get details about the CPUs and 4 of the 8 cores are permanently 100%.  From the time the computer lets me log in to when I shut it down.  But there's nothing in the list of processes even above 5.2%.

When I run perf on each core, I can see that cores zero through 3 are all 100% kernel.

On the desktop of this computer, I noticed a bunch of SELinux errors.  They all appear to be saying that there was an attempt to execute something that should not have been allowed.

And just to confirm that htop was right about what it was reporting, here's the report from the System Monitor.

Booting into a prior version of the kernel didn't help.  And booting into the "rescue" kernel didn't help either.
I tried updating the kernel but that didn't help.  I ran a software update and that didn't help either.  Note that I hadn't done any updates or installed any new software immediately prior to this problem starting.  This install had been stable for years when I needed it.
I also tried installing the same OS over again on a new external drive.  That worked.  No issues on that drive.  But when I boot to that drive and then choose the kernel that is on the main drive, the problem returns.  That all seems to prove that the kernel isn't the issue but the system main drive has something wrong.
I'm at a loss for how to debug further.  I can't figure out what changed and why so I don't know how to even start fixing it.  Any help about where to look and what to check would be appreciated!
--- Edit 1: ---
Here is the additional perf report info that @John Mahowald asked for.  I don't know if the failure to find useful symbols is indicative of the problem I'm chasing, if it is a different issue that I'll need help figure out, or if it is something that should be ignored.

--- Edit 2: ---
Here is the result of vmstat, as requested by @Romeo Ninov


Linux perf_events can show detail about what exactly is on CPU, even cycles not accounted for by user space tasks.   Profile all CPUs for some seconds:  perf record -a -F 999 -- sleep 10   Then review perf.data with command   perf report    Edit your question to include at least the top 10 symbols.

Thanks @John Mahowald, the question has been updated.  And note that I did do the perf work when logged in as root and in /tmp so I don't know why that object file wasn't created.

What is the result of vmstat 1 5?

@ktbos, you have 4 running processes which consume 100% of one core. I will recommend to migrate to the last version of OS. And your question is against the rules because it is about Os which is out of support.

I do have 4 running processes?  Which ones are those?  That's what I've been trying to figure out so could you please point me to how to see those processes?  Then I can start digging into why those processes are running.  As for the "against the rules", sorry, I thought this was more about how to diagnose an issue and my line of questioning didn't seem dependent on OS version.

Symbols are required for humans to interpret the profile, and your kernel appears to be too old to take advantage of /proc/kallsyms.   Install kernel symbols (debuginfo package probably)  and provide the uncompressed vmlinux  binary to  perf report  --vmlinux=
